# DataGrip MySql connection timeout - tableplus+cli both work instantly

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, datagrip

I am attempting to connect to a MySql DB with DataGrip, but it just endlessly fails due to timeouts.

I have successfully connected near-instantly with both TablePlus and by manually sshing in and using mysql in the cli.

The access arrangement is between my laptop: computer A, a gateway machine: computer B, and the database machine: computer C, in the structure:

`A-->B-->C`

My credentials are all present and correct and have been checked and reentered, and are as such:

```
GENERAL
Host: localhost
Port: 3306
User: <username>
Password: <password>
Save: Forever
Database: <database name>

SSH/SSL
Proxy host: C<.url.tld>
Proxy port: 22
Proxy user: <username>
Local port: 3306
Auth type: Key pair (OpenSSH or PuTTY) 
Private key file: <path to ssh key>
Passphrase: <password>
Remember: Forever
```

Also, my ssh config:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host B<.url.tld>
   ForwardAgent yes
   User <username>

Host *<url.tld> !B<url.tld>
   ProxyJump B<.url.tld>
   User <username>
   ForwardAgent yes
```

The logs simply record

`com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: SSH: Error connecting to remote host C<.url.tld>: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)`

with a nice lengthly Java stacktrace of the exact same error over and over again all the way down.

I have tried varying the details in the setup many times and repeatedly got the same error - the only difference is if I deliberately enter my ssh key passphrase incorrectly, it requests it be reentered correctly.

What is going on? How do I fix this and connect to the DB?

Comment: Since you're working with ssh config file you can go to _SSH_ _Configurations_ and choose `OpenSSH config and authentication agent` option for **Authentication type**. 
Could you check it out?